# Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'. Property 'content' is missing in type 'File'

Tags: angular

```
// Import statements
import {DownloadUtil} from "../../shared/util/download/download-util";

// Code sample where error is occurring
downloadReport() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.translate.get('EMPLOYEE_SHIFT_REPORT.retrievingReport').subscribe(response => {
        this.loadingMessage = response;
    });
    this.employeeShiftReportService.downloadReport(this.searchRequest).subscribe(item => {
        this.loading = false;
        //this is where error is occurring  
        DownloadUtil.downloadReport(item);
    }, error => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.loadingMessage = null;
    });
}
```

Error is occurring `Downloadutil.downloadReport(item)`.

Comment: Can you please add proper description on problem?

Comment: Actually i was missing an import statement in service.ts file.